# how to get all lat and lng point by zip code?

Tags: geocoding, google-places

my problem is that 
[image]

as I image see I want all location of by zip code, not just center.
I check many ways just give me response like [google reponse](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&components=postal_code:380050)

but that give northeast and southwest point

but my project wants all the point of that zip code.
how do I get all the points?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible.

There is a very popular feature request that seems like a good fit though:

[Automatic polygon generation to specified geographic boundary](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35816953)